# Read the first message after opening multiple messages

Tags: thunderbird

It seems there is not an active support for thunderbird, so I am going to list my question here instead.

When opening multiple messages like this (usually it's a conversation):

[image: multiple_messages_example.png]

It opens up into 26 tabs and then redirects me to the last tab.

Instead, I want to be redirected to the first opened message.

Thank you.

*EDIT: I want to do this with threaded e-mails, not with individual e-mails.*

Comment: I think that it will always redirect you to the latest message (by date).
If you want a quick way of finding the 1st open message you can use tab switching keys - `Alt+1...9`. For examples you have one tab open initially, you open 26 new tabs. Then you can just press `Alt+2` on the keyboard and it will take you to the first message. If you had more tabs open initially then things get complicated... but still might come handy. :)

Comment: By the way `Alt+1` opens the very first tab and then goes till tab 8.
`Alt+9` opens the very last tab.

Comment: Hahaha It seems I forgot to mention that I have about 13+ already opened tabs. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accidentally found a solution!

All you have to do is sort the messages other way around by date. So that all the new messages will be at the top and all the old messages at the bottom (might need getting used to). See the image.

[image: Thunderbird date settings]

After this, once you open the multiple tabs, it will still open the last tab. But this last tab will be the "first message" you want (or oldest message by date).

P.S. Hopefully I understood you correctly.

P.S.S. You might know this already, but just in case, there is a conversation feature in Thunderbird. Which opens complete conversation in separate tab. The command for it is `Ctrl+Shift+O` or right click + "Open message in Conversation".

Also there the is a more Gmail like conversation style that is available via an add-on. Here is the article about it: [How to Enable Gmail-like Conversation View in Thunderbird](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/enable-conversation-view-mozilla-thunderbird/) and this is the add-on: [Thunderbird Conversations](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/gmail-conversation-view/).

Comment: Sorting by date doesn't resolve the problem. If I double click on the thread as in the example, all messages are opened with the last tab/message being viewed. Yes I know about conversations but it distorts the reading experience (have to resize the reading panel). I'll take a look at the addon and see if it helps. Thanks.

Comment: You mean `Ctrl+O`, not double click right?
Please check this again, because - yes it still opens the last tab (as I said). But the messages in the tabs are sorted other way around. If before they were sorted in ascending order in tabs, now they are sorted in descending order.

Comment: This is how it "looks" -`Tabs: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6`.
`Messages: 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1`.

Comment: Re-rechecked it again. Works for me every time with `Ctrl+O`.

Comment: Just make sure that the arrow next to the Date is pointing upwards (there is no need to double click, click once).

Comment: I see now. It works w/ Ctrl+O only but not w/ threaded message. My inbox is filled with many threaded e-mails (mainly from dev. mailing lists) and I cannot open them w/ Ctrl+O. Thanks for the trick anyway ;)

Comment: As for the add-on, It's convenient and does it's job. But still has minor reading issues (especially with zooming). Eventually, If no one has suggested a solution, I'll mark your answer as accepted _(which is: using your trick w/ Ctrl+O or the add-on w/ threaded e-mails)_.